# How to really disconnect from WebSocket using OkHttpClient?

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket, network-programming, okhttp

I'm trying to disconnect from WebSocket connection, but it's listener is still alive, I can see that websockets are still recreating by "OPEN/FAIL" messages using System.out messages.

On the one hand I've tried to release connection in `finally` block using `client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown()` method, but it rejects other future calls (so it doesn't fit), on the other using `client.connectionPool().evictAll()` doesn't help either (even if I wait, because it may not exit immediately based on docs https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/)

There is WebSocketListener code:

```
class WebSocketConnectionListener(
    private val updateConnectionValue: (internetConnection: Boolean) -> Unit,
    private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    private val urlAddress: String
) : WebSocketListener() {

    companion object {
        private const val NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000
    }

    private var isConnected = true
    private var webSocketN: WebSocket? = null

    init {
        createWebSocket()
    }

    override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
        println("OPEN: ${response.code}")
        isConnected = true
        updateConnectionValue(true)
        reconnect(webSocket)
    }

    override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
        println("FAIL: $t")
        if (!isConnected) {
            updateConnectionValue(false)
        }
        isConnected = false
        reconnect(webSocket)
    }

    private fun createWebSocket() {
        val request = Request.Builder().url(urlAddress).build()
        webSocketN = okHttpClient.newWebSocket(request, this)
    }

    private fun reconnect(webSocket: WebSocket) {
        webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null)
        webSocketN?.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, "Connection closed")
        webSocketN = null

        Thread.sleep(3_000)
        createWebSocket()
    }
}
```

There is DataSource implementation code:

```
class InternetConnectionDataSourceImpl(
    private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    private val urlAddress: String
) : InternetConnectionDataSource {

    private fun createWebSocketListener(
        internetConnectionFlow: MutableStateFlow<Boolean>,
    ) = WebSocketConnectionListener(
        updateConnectionValue = { internetConnectionFlow.value = it },
        okHttpClient = okHttpClient,
        urlAddress = urlAddress
    )

    override suspend fun checkConnection(): Flow<Boolean> =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val internetConnectionFlow = MutableStateFlow(true)
            createWebSocketListener(internetConnectionFlow)

            flow {
                try {
                    internetConnectionFlow.collect {
                        emit(it)
                    }
                } finally {
                    println("finally")
                    okHttpClient.connectionPool.evictAll()
                }
            }
        }
}
```

As the result I'm getting this messages in logcat
[image: log messages]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WebSocket.close() for a graceful shutdown or cancel() for an immediate one.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-web-socket/